# how em embed font and bold fonts in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I use flex4.5
I have this simple question: I need to embed normal and Bold Arial fonts to my application:
I tried that:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";    
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

@font-face {
    src:url("assets/arial.ttf");
    fontFamily: arial;
}

global
{
    font-size: 12;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: arial;

}
```

This works fine, except the BOLD fonts were still aliased.

Then I tried that:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";    
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

@font-face {
    src:url("assets/arial.ttf");
    fontFamily: arial;
}

@font-face {
    src:url("assets/arial.ttf");
    fontFamily: arial;
    fontWeight:bold;
}

global
{
    font-size: 12;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: arial;

}
```

Bold fonts are not aliased any more, but they are displayed as normal fonts !

My question is : how to embed BOLD and Not BOLD fonts in Flex4.5 Css so both are displayed anti aliased ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the font with the bold variant `arial-bold` or something similar, and then use that as the font family in your style declarations. You will also need to set the `font-weight` style to `bold`.

Comment: trouble is that some components use BOLD naturally like header on TitleWindow or formElements.

I also use some HTML texts like : <B>hello</B>world